# How practically to determine dispersion's Hamaker constant using CCC?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, colloids

I know that Hamaker constants can be determined from CCC data.
$$ccc=\frac{9.85 \cdot 10^4 \epsilon^3 k_B^5 T^5 \gamma^4}{N_A e^6 A^2 Z^6}$$
Where, $\epsilon$ is solvent dielectric constant, $N_A$ is Avagadro constant, $k_B$ is Bolcman constant, $Z$ is electrolite charge, T is temperature of solution, A is Hamaker constant, e is electron charge.

$\gamma=\frac{exp(Z e \psi_0 )/2k_B T+1}{exp(Z e \psi_0 )/2k_B T-1}$.

I can get all constants to determine A except for $\gamma$. Where can I get $\gamma$ values?
Lets assume, that I have CuS stabilized by oleic acid nanoparticles dispersed in hexane, how do I practically find $\gamma$? I can grasp that $\psi_0$ is somehow related to zeta-potential.